# some discord bot command aliases work and some don't, not getting any errors?

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

So I'm creating a discord bot, and it seems to work perfectly other than one thing: sometimes, command aliases don't work. They just don't get a response.

I suspected it might have had to do with apostrophes/special characters, but after some testing I concluded that both of those don't cause the error. Then, I thought it might be an issue with the length of the alias, but I tested it with a random long word as an alias and it worked fine. I've googled around and found nothing about the limits of aliases or why this might be happening, so I'm completely at a loss.

Here's the code for one of my commands that's bugging out:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const colors = require("../../colors.json");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setColor(colors.purple)
    .setAuthor('FIREFLY CURSE', 'placeholder.image.link', 'placeholder.link')
    .setDescription("placeholder description")
    .setThumbnail('placeholder.image.link')
    .addField('Test', 'X', false)
    .addField('Test', "Y", false);
    message.channel.send({embed:embed});
}

module.exports.config = {
    name: "firefly curse",
aliases: ["fireflycurse", "fireflyc", "fc", "firefly curse", "supercalifragilisticexpialidocious", "test'test", "test test", "numbertest",]
}
```

Above lists the aliases I tried. All work except for "firefly curse" and "test test". This made me think the space was the issue, BUT in a *different* command, an alias with a space *does* work. There are absolutely no differences between the code besides different text in the text within the embed, which shouldn't be affecting the execution of the code itself.

Command handler code:

```
const fs = require("fs");
bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();
bot.aliases = new Discord.Collection();

async function load(dir){
fs.readdir(`./commands/${dir}/`, (err, files) => {
        if(err) console.log(err)

        let jsfile = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop);
        if(jsfile.length <= 0) {
            return console.log("commands missing!");
        }

    jsfile.forEach((f, i) => {
        let pull = require(`./commands/${dir}/${f}`)
        bot.commands.set(pull.config.name, pull);  
        pull.config.aliases.forEach(alias => {
            bot.aliases.set(alias, pull.config.name)

        })
    })
});
}
```

Bot.on code block:

```
bot.on("message", async message => {
    if(message.author.bot || message.channel.type === "dm") return;

    let prefix = botconfig.prefix;
    let messageArray = message.content.split(" ")
    let cmd = messageArray[0];
    let args = messageArray.slice(1);

    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    let commandfile = bot.commands.get(cmd.slice(prefix.length)) || bot.commands.get(bot.aliases.get(cmd.slice(prefix.length)))
    if(commandfile) commandfile.run(bot,message,args)

})
```

Comment: Please show the command handler code (how it detects if a message is a command and how it stores commands).

Comment: added to the main post (i think? i may have missed some since i'm not sure exactly what you're referring to)

Answer (score 1):

You want to make command that runs like `!say hello` so the bot will send `hello` message. There is no need to add aliases for this like `say hello`.

In your bot script everything is correct except one mistake:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const colors = require("../../colors.json");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

    if(args[0] === 'curse'){

    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor(colors.purple)
    .setAuthor('FIREFLY CURSE', 'placeholder.image.link', 'placeholder.link')
    .setDescription("placeholder description")
    .setThumbnail('placeholder.image.link')
    .addField('Test', 'X', false)
    .addField('Test', "Y", false);
    message.channel.send({embed:embed});
}
}

module.exports.config = {
    name: "firefly",
    aliases: []
}
```

Now try the command `!firefly curse`, this would work!

Answer (score 0):

Pls show your `bot.on message` block.

As usual bot commands slice with spases, so if command name have spaces, its cant be handled by command hendler

P.S. sorry for ask it in answer, can`t write comments :C

Comment: added to the main post. I wish it were as simple as spaces, but like I mentioned, it *does* work in some situations

Comment: yes your cmd its a fist word in the message, so when you try to get command with spaces alies, bot cant find it. As reason you can add condition:
`if(!commandfile && messageArray.length > 1)
     messageArray = message.content.split(" ")
     cmd = messageArray.splice(0,2).join(' ')
     args = messageArray.slice(2);
commandfile = bot.commands.get(cmd.slice(prefix.length)) || bot.commands.get(bot.aliases.get(cmd.slice(prefix.length)))
if(commandfile) commandfile.run(bot,message,args)`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code where you are getting the command from the message, you'll need to factor in that spaces can be in command, as well as arguments.
Right now, you are only expecting and getting the first word of the message, and making that the key for the commands map, however, you should also allow the first element of the arguments to allow spaces:

```js
if (!message.content.startsWith(botconfig.prefix)) return;

const args = message.content.slice(botconfig.prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();
// this is a simplified way to get the command, removing the prefix and creating the arguments

let commandfile = bot.commands.get(cmd.slice(prefix.length)) || bot.commands.get(bot.aliases.get(cmd.slice(prefix.length)))

const commandFile = args.length === 0 ? bot.commands.get(cmd) || bot.commands.get(bot.aliases.get(cmd)) : bot.commands.get(cmd  + ' ' + args[0]) || bot.commands.get(bot.aliases.get(cmd + ' ' + args[0])) || bot.commands.get(cmd) || bot.commands.get(bot.aliases.get(cmd));
// the ternary operator

if (commandfile) commandfile.run(bot,message,args)
```

If you're not familiar with [`ternary operators`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), then this is the code expanded:

```js
let commandFile;
if (args.length === 0) {
  commandFile = bot.commands.get(cmd) || bot.commands.get(bot.aliases.get(cmd));
  // this will only run if there are no arguments in the message. You can expect the command to have no spaces
} else {
  commandFile = bot.commands.get(cmd  + ' ' + args[0]) || bot.commands.get(bot.aliases.get(cmd + ' ' + args[0])) || bot.commands.get(cmd) || bot.commands.get(bot.aliases.get(cmd));
  // since the arguments length is larger than 0, the cmd + (space) + first index of arguments may be a command or alias, so check for that first. If there isn't any found, check if cmd is a command or alias
}
```

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but I'm not sure how to incorporate your code into my own. (tried quite a few different methods to replace existing arg/cmd variables to no avail) If it's not too much trouble, could you be more specific with what I need to replace?

Comment: I've only used your code (and replaced that section) in the `message` event, and simply changed a few lines.